# Emacs 23.3 lost all fonts

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I've updated Emacs from 23.1 to 23.3 and it suddenly can no longer find my fonts (for example Liberation Mono). When I try to Options->Set Default Font... I'm prompted with a very bizarre choice of things some called using the format of "AxB", where A and B are digits, some have remotely recognizable names (like lucildatypewriter - although I don't have any font installed by that name, neither "Lucilda Typewriter" nor anything remotely similar), the "Lucilda" family has some more "relatives" - for example: "lucildatypewriter-bold-14", but the choice of weight / size is arbitrary. It has one more menu entirely dedicated to Courier font and one small menu, which says "fontsets" and contains two items: "standart 17-dot medium" and "startup 16-dot medium", both, obviously don't name any fonts.

The font it chosen for displaying the code is some serif font, and it looks extremely bad...

When I try to customize the default face `M-x customize-face RET default` It says that it is using `times` - again, I don't have times installed, the font I have is the "Times New Roman".

I've also tried eval'ing

```
(set-face-attribute
 'default nil
 :family "Liberation Mono" :height 100)
```

but it had no visible effect.

Below is my fonts.conf:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<match target="font" qual="all">
<edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
<edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
<int>0</int>
</edit>
<edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
</match>
<fontconfig>
```

*(I don't want to use AA for fonts)*

```
 fc-list
```

will print the fonts I'd like to use and was using in the previous version of Emacs. I'm using Ubuntu / GTK if that matters.

What would I need to do to explain emacs where my fonts are installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the fonts gone when you start emacs with `emacs -q` too?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when using a version of Emacs configured without GTK support. Recompiling Emacs with GTK configured allowed me to again see all the expected fonts.